# How to Convert String to DateTime in specified format?

Tags: datetime

string date="8/13/2010"; // mm/dd/yyyy

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci =System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
 string CurrDateFormat = ci.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern.ToString() -- **// dd/mm/yyyy**

DateTime dt=Convert.ToDateTime(date);  ***// Exception : In valid date time format***

date=dt.ToString(CurrDateFormat ,ci);
```

This is the code i written.

**I want to display DateTime in UI as per the current Culture Date Time Format**

Please help me how to solve the problem.

Thanks
Kiran G

Comment: Please specify what language or system you are using, and tag the question accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
DateTime result;
DateTime.TryParse("8/13/2010", out result);
```

For error handling, you can put an `if` statement around the `DateTime.TryParse` method as this returns a `boolean` value.