# Convert String with GMT foramt to Datetime

Tags: c#, datetime

How to convert "Fri Jul 11 2014 01:30:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)" to Datetime 
with the format of "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" in C#?

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3511578/how-to-convert-string-to-datetime-in-specified-format?rq=1

Comment: If it is dupe, any solution will be accepted please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert UTC/GMT time to local time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179940/convert-utc-gmt-time-to-local-time)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19879817/c-sharp-parse-gmt-date-string-to-datetime?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String inputString="Fri Jul 11 2014 01:30:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)";
// we have no need of the parenthetical, get rid of it
inputString = Regex.Replace(inputString, " \\(.*\\)$", "");
// exact string format ... 'GMT' is literal
DateTime theDate = DateTime.ParseExact(inputString,"ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'zzz",
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```